# speicif HTTP url to HTTPS url (only one url)

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I was searching on web for like 4 hours and tryeda almoast everything, but nothing worked.

All i want to do is force redirecting for norma url to https url, using .htaccess, example:

I want that when person visit:
- http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_dms&task=checkout&Itemid=816

See:
- https://www.mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_dms&task=checkout&Itemid=816

that's pretty much all, I hope this is simple enough.

Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To do it only for your URL, this should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^http://www\.mydomain\.com/index\.php?option=com_dms&task=checkout&Itemid=816$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Replace the URL by .* for all traffic.